# Create a table to match user input with another data

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a very simple, beginner level Battleship game using Python. So far, I have two classes `Player` and `Ship`, and one Ship method `place_ship` to keep track of the location of a ship on the game board.

Ship's `direction` (horizontal or vetical), `starting_x`, and `starting_y` will be taken from user input. Then, based on that input the ship will be created and placed on the board using the `place_ship` function. The problem is that I need to make mathematical operations to store and check the location of a ship when there's an attack but since the board's x indices are letters: A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J I want to use that while taking input from the user and not numbers. However, for calculations, I need to use integers. How can I match A with 1 , B with 2, and so on in the back based on the user input?

```
class Player:
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.is_turn = False
    self.is_winner = False
    self.num_ships = 10

  def __repr__(self):
    return "Hello {name}, welcome to Battle Ship! You currently have {num_ships} ships. Place them on the board and get ready!".format(name = self.name, num_ships = self.num_ships)
  
class Ship:
  def __init__(self, ship_type, length, direction, strating_x, strating_y):
    self.type = ship_type
    self.length = length
    self.Lives = length
    self.direction = direction
    self.strating_x = strating_x
    self.strating_y = strating_y
    self.ending_x = 0
    self.ending_y = 0
    #stores the coordinates the ships are placed on
    self.ship_placement = {}
  
  #Places ship on the board
  def place_ship(self):
    if self.direction.upper == "V":
      self.ending_x = self.starting_x
      self.ending_y = self.starting_y + self.length
      for y in range(self.starting_y, self.ending_y + 1):
        ship_placement[self.ship_type].append(starting_x + str(y))
    elif self.direction.upper == "H":
      self.ending_x = self.starting_x + self.length
      self.ending_y = self.starting_y
      for x in range(self.starting_x, self.ending_x + 1):
        ship_placement[self.ship_type].append(str(x) + starting_y)
    else:
      return "Error: Input couldn't be processed"
  
  def __repr__(self):
    return "Your {ship_type} is placed between {starting_x}{starting_y} and {ending_x}{ending_y}"
```

Comment: `locations = {'A': 1, 'B': 2, ...}`

Comment: `string.ascii_uppercase.index(starting_x)`, possibly `+ 1`.

Comment: `chr(starting_x + 65)`, a simple arithmetic formula.